# How can I get the sequence number of mssg from ServiceBusReceiver ReceiveMessageAsync

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

How do I get the sequence number of a message I retrieve from a service bus queue

```
ServiceBusReceivedMessage receivedStateMessage = await busreceiver_State.ReceiveMessageAsync();
```

(note-not the message received by ServiceBusTrigger binding)?

```
[FunctionName("TelemetryListenerCalculateAlgoPostNewState")]
    public static async Task TelemetryListenerCalculateAlgoPostNewState(
        [ServiceBusTrigger(busTelemetryQueueName,Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]
        string [] receivedTelemetryMessages,
        Int32 [] DeliveryCountArray,
        DateTime [] EnqueuedTimeUtcArray,
        string [] MessageIdArray,
        Int64[] SequenceNumberArray,
        ILogger log)
    {
        await using ServiceBusClient bus_client = new ServiceBusClient(ServiceBusConnection);
        var newStateJson = "";
        Algorithm_SaveStateVariables priorState = new Algorithm_SaveStateVariables();
        List<IncomingTelemetry> retrievedQueuedTelemetryList = new List<IncomingTelemetry>();

        #region Receive prior state message
        ServiceBusReceiverOptions stateReceiverOptions = new ServiceBusReceiverOptions();
        stateReceiverOptions.PrefetchCount = 1;
        stateReceiverOptions.ReceiveMode = ServiceBusReceiveMode.PeekLock;
        ServiceBusReceiver busreceiver_State = bus_client.CreateReceiver(busStateQueueName, stateReceiverOptions);
        ServiceBusReceivedMessage receivedStateMessage = await busreceiver_State.ReceiveMessageAsync();
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need all the lower-level information about the messages, you might consider receiving an array of `ServerBusReceivedMessage`. With that, you'll have access to all the information about each message.

Comment: thanks a lot @Sean Feldman, works great. Odd that EnqueuedSequenceNum property is always 0 despite that's the original sequence number of the message whilst SequenceNumber is unique number assigned to a message, the latter feels less likely to keep the order count